# PHP Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load fro

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

This used to work on my old setup but I have moved from Win7 to Win8 using WAMP and now I get this.

PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://webservices.quova.com/OnDemand/GeoPoint/v1/default.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://webservices.quova.com/OnDemand/GeoPoint/v1/default.asmx?WSDL"\n in E:\{MY PATH}\Init.php on line 57

```
$OnDmd_service = new SoapClient('https://webservices.quova.com/OnDemand/GeoPoint/v1/default.asmx?WSDL',$OD_PasswordHdr);
```

Here are my settings:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On

;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll 
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_phar.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll
```

Is there anything else I can check for or do? All the other posts I saw related to this seemed to be fixed by activating a extension or plugin but mine are already activated and still do not work. I also tried loading the url without the secure only "http" and same result. I can access it from the browser.

What should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I need to add this to the options:

```
'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array('ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does error says the same (non secure url) when you try to access https url?

In most cases that means that WSDL is not accessible.

Ensure that url is valid and starts with https, clear or disable wsdl cache and retry.